# Crystal Report XI If statement not working: not getting to else

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a problem with an `If statement` in Crystal Reports XI.

This is my code:

```
IF {ANAGRAFICACF.CODLINGUA} = {DESCRARTICOLI.LINGUA}
THEN
  {DESCRARTICOLI.DESCRIZIONEAGG}
ELSE
   {RIGHEDOCUMENTI.DESCRIZIONEART};
```

The problem is that Crystal Reports retrieves only lines with the condition verified and completely ignores the else condition. So if in my documents there are 10 lines, it show me the only 2 that have the condition verified.
Can you explain why? I think this is OK.  It's only a simple `if statement`.

There more details as you request:

I tryed also this code

```
    IF NOT ISNULL({DESCRARTICOLI.DESCRIZIONEAGG}) AND {TESTEDOCUMENTI.CODLINGUA} <>0 
THEN
{DESCRARTICOLI.DESCRIZIONEAGG}
ELSE
{RIGHEDOCUMENTI.DESCRIZIONEART}
```

For this last code I have this structure:
TESTEDOCUMENTI.CODLINGUA is numeric like in all other tables. So for English I've "1" for default I've "0"
DESCRARTICOLI.DESCRIZIONEAGG is the translation, so in DESCRARTICOLI
I've for example CODART CODLINGUA DESCRARTICOLI (Article code, Language Code, Article Translated Description)
RIGHEDOCUMENTI.DESCRIZIONEART is the standard italian description that I see in my ERP. So I've different columns including IDRIGA CODART DESCRIZIONEART  (Line ID, Article Code, Italian Language Description)
Then I've TESTEDOCUMENTI table that contain the language CODLINGUA between columns. This table has the general setting of a single document.
So in my Cristal Report table setup I've linked the 3 tables RIGHEDOCUMENTI TESTEDOCUMENTI and DESCRARTICOLI and in particular TESTEDOCUMENTI.CODLINGUA with DESCRARTICOLI.CODLINGUA and RIGHEDOCUMENTI.CODART with DESCRARTICOLI.CODART.

When the translation is not stored in the article in the erp the DESCRARTICOLI.DESCRIZIONEAGG for this Article code doesn't exist. For example. If my CODART is "abg" in RIGHEDOCUMENTI I've CODART "abg" DESCRIZIONEART "ciao". Then in DESCRARTICOLI I've CODART "abg" CODLINGUA "1" DESCRIZIONEAGG "hI". If the translation is not stored the line in DESCRARTICOLI doesn't exist.

So my need is to verify if TESTEDOCUMENTI.CODLINGUA is different from "0" default language, but this is not enough because, most of my article hasn't the translation stored. So I need to show, the italian one, or a simple message telling me "no translation stored". I've tryed also to put this message instead of RIGHEDOCUMENTI.DESCRIZIONEART but it doesn't appear.

Another strange thing is that, in my document, on the same line I've also, in separate field in the report, the CODEART, MEASURES, PRICE. If I put directly RIGHEDOCUMENTI.DESCRIZIONEART without if statement, I see all those fields. Insted in I put the if statement I don't see neither thouse other fields..

It seems like that the first think it go to read the Translation Table DESCRARTICOLI, it doesn't come back to read the original one, so end the cicle through lines, without reading all parameters stored in the RIGHEDOCUMENTI tables, containing all data that don't appear in the report.

I hope to have been more clear now. 
Thank you!

Comment: Are you certain that `RIGHEDOCUMENTI.DESCRIZIONEART` is correctly spelled and/or has data?  One thing to possibly check is to add a hard-coded string in the else clause, temporarily, (for example "I am else!") to see if the string appears in the output.

Comment: Descrizioneart has always a value. Instead descrizioneagg may be null. They are in 2 different tables linked by codeart. When I compile the report from my erp, I obtain only lines with descrizioneagg but no one that doesn't have it. Yes tried also to put "nodata" but it doesn't appear the same. I link tables with codeart inner join and language with the language field of the same table and the customer table also inner join

Comment: can you please post data types on these fields {ANAGRAFICACF.CODLINGUA} and 
{DESCRARTICOLI.LINGUA} and sample data

Comment: Can you add some details like the data source type, if you're using some other language or IDE, or other details to provide more context?

Comment: I've updated my first post. Thank you!